# AWS ELB to multiple EC2s with subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

First things first, I don't know how AWS components work or are configured. I'm just designing an architecture from a top perspective, and then some sysadmin is going to implement it.

If I have an ELB and EC2 instances either running a HTTPS server or accepting WSS connections using a wildcard certificate (`server1.domain.com`, `server2.domain.com`...), should the ELB listen to  different ports (like ELB:443 -> server1, ELB:444 server2...) or can it listen just to 443 and 8080 (for WSS) and then redirect to the specific server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELB does not work like that. ELB will take requests and forward them to any EC2 instance that is listening behind it. You cannot direct requests to specific EC2 instances in any way (port, domain, etc.).

If you want certain domains to go to specific EC2 instances, then you would either map your domain to the EC2 instances directly via your DNS server (and use Elastic IP addresses), or you would have individual ELBs infront of the different EC2 instances.

Comment: but, does it make sense to have multiple load balancers public facing?

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple public facing websites